# Cron.d doesn't run my command

Tags: debian, cron

I am trying to execute a command using cron.d. I've tried so far this to test

```
11 13 * * * root echo \"OK?\" >/tmp/cron-is-ok
```

which runs fine! Runs as it should. But if I replace the command with

```
11 13 * * * root useradd -ou 0 -g 0 john1
```

It doesn't run. I tried shell script like this

```
11 13 * * * root /home/myUser/Downloads/ascript.sh
```

but it also doesn't run. There is the `#!/bin/bash` header in the beginning. I'm using Debian and I read that the name of the script must not have `.`. Tried it, also doesn't work.

If I run the command and script from terminal as a root user it works fine. Any hints?

Comment: did cron tell you any error? `systemctl status cron` tells me a lot of *job ... started for user ...* and *job ... completed* if its successfull and *job ... failed* if not. you can also check if cron sent you any mail by just executing `mail` as the first user you created on your system (mails get redirected to that one)

Comment: I added a MAILTO="my@mail.gr" but didn't receive any email

Comment: the mail will be sent to your local smtp server (if present), so add <user>@<hostname>.localdomain

Comment: Nevermind I found it i had to set path on the top of the file

Comment: If your problem is fixed, please write an answer, or close the question.

Comment: A nitpick. cron.d is a subdirectory whereas crond is a daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the script: make sure the script has execute permissions (`chmod u+x /home/myUser/Downloads/ascript.sh`)?

Regarding the `useradd` statement: does this make sense? You're creating a duplicate user with the same UID and GID as root!

Comment: As far as the useradd command I want just that to add a second root user at specified time. It's homework for software security class.